# How to run batch file as with admin privileges

Tags: windows-10, administrator

I need to run a batch file on a users desktop and run it with admin privileges to restart a service. I can get the batch file to work when I am logged in as local admin

Here is the script, please help

```
NET LOCALGROUP administrators "NT Authority\Local Service" /add
netsh winsock reset catalog
Set /p <nul = "Your PC needs to reboot to Finish applying Changes. press any key to reboot." & pause > nul
Shutdown -r -t 1
```

Or can any one give me a way to run the cmd as a user without needing admin rights

Comment: "can any one give me a way to run the cmd as a user without needing admin rights" - The command you are attempting to use requires the script's permissions to be elevated and then ran ran as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to recycle a service, you can use the SC command

Fire up command prompt and type

SC \\hostname stop servicename

SC \\hostname start servicename

You could stick that into a .bat file with a localhost ping to act as a dummy sleep, as you'll need to wait for the service to stop before you can start it again.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run scripts as scheduled tasks with elevated privileges using the Windows Task Scheduler so that may be an option. Note that you would want to be careful to prevent any standard users from being able to edit the script so that they cannot introduce arbitrary commands which would be run as an elevated user, that would be a huge security vulnerability.